# "Virtual File System" (VFS) folders names

Tags: c#, c++, appv

I need to create a "Virtual File System" (VFS) Folder similar to those included with an AppV package.

Does anyone know how "KNOWN SYSTEM FOLDERS" names are resolved to the equivalent Virtual File System folders names.

For example; examining the content of the VFS folder from an AppV package physical system paths get resolved as;

- "C:\Program Files (x86)" to "VFS\ProgramFilesX86"
- "C:\ProgramData" to "VFS\Common%20AppData"
- "C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming" to "VFS\AppData"
- "C:\Windows\SysWOW64" to "VFS\SystemX86"

Does exist a WINAPI at such purpose?

Any information is really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Check out Environment.GetFolderPath  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to worry about VFS, just **use the** **KNOWNFOLDERSID**s as given by [MSDN.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457(v=vs.85).aspx)

The App-V client handles the redirecation of the calls from your code to the correct paths in a VFS environment.

As long as you use **relative paths and KNOWNFOLDERIDs** your app will run just fine, without *knowing* or *caring* if it is running as a standard desktop app or as an app-v one.

**DON'T** ever use hardcoded paths in your code.